# How each individual rows hold different number of items?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

This is the program of a Jagged Array( in Java ). Can you please explain each lines shortly? I couldn't understand how this program works actually!

```
    int r = 5; 
    int arr[][] = new int[r][]; 
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
        arr[i] = new int[i+1]; 
    int count = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
        for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) 
            arr[i][j] = count++; 
    System.out.println("Contents of 2D Jagged Array"); 
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
    { 
        for (int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) 
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " "); 
        System.out.println();


*OUTPUT*:
0 
1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Let's start with the following two line:**

```
int r = 5; 
int arr[][] = new int[r][];
```

The second line declares a 2-D array for `int` values. A 2-D array in Java is an array of arrays. You can think of a table of 5 rows where the length of rows has not been declared yet.

**Next two lines:**

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
    arr[i] = new int[i+1];
```

You are declaring the length of each row using this loop. The first row (i.e. `arr[0]`) has been assigned a length of `0 + 1 = 1`. The second row (i.e. `arr[1]`) has been assigned a length of `1 + 1 = 2` and so on.

**Next four lines:**

```
int count = 0; 
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
    for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) 
        arr[i][j] = count++;
```

Using this nested loop, you are filling up the cells of this table e.g.

```
arr[0][0] = 0
arr[1][0] = 1
arr[1][1] = 2
arr[2][0] = 3
arr[2][1] = 4
arr[2][2] = 5
and so on...
```

**And finally,**

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { 
    for (int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " "); 
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Using this nested loop, you are printing the values in each cell of the table. Note that value of each cell is being printed in the same line using `System.out.print` whereas a line break is printed using `System.out.println()` once the value of a row is printed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code defines different columns for each row, for the first iteration will create one column then two and three and four, etc

```
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
        for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) 
            arr[i][j] = count++;
```

, And printing the array

```
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { 
        for (int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) 
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " "); 
        System.out.println();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have commented on each important line, hope it is clear. For any doubt ask me.

**CODE**

```
    int r = 5;
    // I create a jagged array with r "big" cells
    int[][] arr = new int[r][];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        // Inside each i-th "big" cell I create a "small" array with i+1 cells
        arr[i] = new int[i + 1];
    int count = 0;
    // For each "big" cell I manage the "small" array inside it
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        // For each cell of the "small" array, I insert the variable "count"'s value ++
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
            arr[i][j] = count++;
    System.out.println("Contents of 2D Jagged Array");
    // Let's print the jagged array content by analyzing each "big" cell of it
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Contents of 2D Jagged Array
0 
1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14
```

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction to "Jagged" arrays**

First, in the literal sense there are no such things as `2-D` arrays in Java.  They are really just regular arrays that hold other arrays (which could also hold other arrays and so on).  But they are referred to that as a short hand because it is easy and everyone still knows what you are talking about.

So here is how they can become what is known as a `jagged` array.

First allocate the array.  The second "dimension" need not be specified.  It basically indicates the type that this will hold, which is a regular array.

```
int[][] arrays = new int[3][];
```

Now create an array with values.

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

And assign it to slot 0 of `array`

```
arrays[0] = a;
```

Now do it again.  Not that the same variable is being used but it will refer to a new instance of an array.  The previous instance has already been stored in `array[0]`

```
a = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
arrays[1] = a;
```

And again

```
a = new int[] {10,11,12,14};
arrays[2] = a;
```

Now print them.  Just like you would get, say an int from an array of ints, you are getting an array from an array of arrays.

```
for (int [] v : arrays) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[10, 11, 12, 14]
```

Or like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(arrays[i][j] + " " );
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Prints

```
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 5 
10 11 12
```

**Now about your program.**

This should look familiar

```
int r = 5; 
int arr[][] = new int[r][];
```

Each arr element is being assigned a newly allocated array of length `i+1`. But no values are being stored, just the allocated arrays.

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
        arr[i] = new int[i+1];
```

Now in a nested loop, the outer loop indexes `arr` and the inner loop indexes the newly assigned arrays.  But as it accesses them it fills them with the current value of count.

```
int count = 0; 
// index the outer array
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
// uses the length field of the assigned array as a limit
   for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) 
       arr[i][j] = count++;
```

And this just prints them as shown above.

```
System.out.println("Contents of 2D Jagged Array"); 
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { 
    for (int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) 
       System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " "); 
    System.out.println();
```

Prints

```
Contents of 2D Jagged Array
0 
1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14
```